# Is it possible to programmatically retrieve link clicks from iislogs?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, api, vbscript, xmlhttprequest

We have an app built by a vendor that gives our users the ability to see events and their dates.

A user can search for an event by searching by either specific date, date range, or by event name.

If found, the results are displayed as links and users can click these links to view details.

We are interested in capturing the number of clicks by visitors to the site.

Since the app is not built by us, we are unable to figure out a way to retrieve how many times a user or site visitor clicks on a particular link on a particular page.

We can, however, open an iislog in windows\system32 directory to grab information about click counts.

My question is whether there is a way to programmatically retrieve link click counts on a particular page from iislogs?

Thanks in advance.